# how to use the removechild() to remove an xml element?

Tags: nativescript

Is there any examples on how to use removechild(), because I need to delete certain xml element via code

I know I could use visible attribute but I want to remove the element completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [removeChild](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_layouts_layout_base_.layoutbase#removechild) method on your parent layout. Let's assume you have a `StackLayout` and want to remove a `Button` inside, upon click

**XML**

```
<StackLayout id="parentLyt">
   <Button text="Remove me" tap="onButtonTap"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**JS**

```
exports.onButtonTap = function(args) {
    var button = args.object;
    var page = button.page;
    page.getViewById('parentLyt').removeChild(button);
};
```